# Manipulating data from one array, to affect another array using numpy

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

So my problem is I have two parallel arrays

B = np.array([250 , 270, 120, 100 , 200, 300])
A = np.array([1 , 2, 5, 6, 1, 4])

So, if the values in each indices are linked (250 - 1, 270 - 2 , 120 - 5, etc) I want to eliminate any value in the B array that has an even number in the A array.

How would I go along and do that? Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> b = np.array([250, 270, 120, 100, 200, 300])
>>> a = np.array([1, 2, 5, 6, 1, 4])
>>> b[a % 2 != 0]
array([250, 120, 200])
```

If array 'a' is longer than array 'b', then I think you'll need to do something like this:

```
>>> b[a[:len(b)] % 2 != 0]
```

Comment: thanks! I applied the concept to my code, but I get the error "ValueError: too many boolean indices". What does that mean?

Comment: I think it might be because array a is longer than array b. I've updated my answer.